Unity 3D: Instantiating an object after setting it into a list isn't consistent
I am making a game where people walk around catching cats then releasing them into a safe spot.
Here's all the relevant code:
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Unity.VisualScripting;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerCatching : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text playerScore;
    private int playerScoreInt;

    public Text catHoldCount;
    public List<GameObject> cats;
    GameObject tempGameObject;
    private int catCount;


    private void Start()
    {
        playerScoreInt = 0;
        cats = new List<GameObject>();
        playerScore.text = playerScoreInt.ToString();
        tempGameObject = null;
        catCount = 0;
    }
    private void Update()
    {
        playerScore.text = playerScoreInt.ToString();
        catHoldCount.text = catCount.ToString();

        if (catCount < 0)
        {
            catCount = 0;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            if (catCount >= 1)
            {
                GameObject releaseCat = cats[cats.Count - 1];

                Vector3 catReleasePosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1, transform.position.z);
                GameObject newObject = Instantiate(releaseCat, catReleasePosition, transform.rotation);
                newObject.SetActive(true);

                catCount--;
                Destroy(cats[cats.Count - 1]);
                cats.RemoveAt(cats.Count - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E) && other.gameObject.CompareTag("Cat") && (catCount < 3))
        {
            playerScoreInt++;
            tempGameObject = Instantiate(other.gameObject);
            tempGameObject.SetActive(false);
            cats.Add(tempGameObject);
            catCount++;

            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
        //Debug.Log("Collided with " + other.ToString());
    }
}

Thanks in advance for any help
I was able to get the core mechanic of getting the cat and (to some degree) releasing them. However, when the player object releases cats, it sometimes doesn't release them (note: I checked the inspector and they do instantiate and set themselves to active). For example, I take 3 cats (works every time), then I press "F" 3 times  to release 3 cats, but sometimes only 2 release. Another example is that if I press F 3 times, but press them with some delay after each other, all 3 release attempts are successful, but if I press F 3 times really fast, 1 or 2 cats don't release.
I hope someone can tell me if there's some weird Unity shenanigans going on.
I am also sure that I am not prematurely deleting the cats when I release them.
Edit:
This function works perfectly when I Build and Run the game. It seems that it only has the inconsistent problem of spawning the cats (exists in inspector, but doesn't show in the game preview). Could this be because of the code block? :
if (catCount >= 1)
        {
            GameObject releaseCat = cats[cats.Count - 1];

            Vector3 catReleasePosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1, transform.position.z);
            GameObject newObject = Instantiate(releaseCat, catReleasePosition, transform.rotation);
            newObject.SetActive(true);

            catCount--;
            Destroy(cats[cats.Count - 1]);
            cats.RemoveAt(cats.Count - 1);
        }


the shenanigans will be your own.  Add some debug statements.. it seems, you destroy and instantiate cats at the same time.. You would benefit from a pooling system, but if its not working as you expect then you need to add debug statements/debug whats going on

yeah that might lead to problems, since I did assume that the code should work linearly in the update function. Do they tend to not work linearly in Unity's editor, which was why I was experiencing problems in the SDK, but not on the built game?

well update happens per frame.. but the others can span frames as far as i know but you will also run into gc issues

Cute idea!
First of all, some ideas to simplify and optimise your code:

Don't use a separate variable for catCount when you already have the List's cats.Count value. It's completely redundant and adds a bunch of extra code to sync these values.

Don't keep deleting and reinstantiating the cats from the cats list. Rather, when a cat is picked up, disable the object and add it to the list. Then when it is put down, activate it and remove it from the list. You already have the GameObjects instantiated and referenced there. If you really need  a reference to all cats at any given time, then do this with a new list (or an array if the total amount doesn't change) called allCats instead.

I can't imagine why, in your OnTriggerStay method, you'd be creating a new instance of the object you collided with, then disable it, then destroy the original. That makes little to no sense to me. Perhaps don't do this.


It seems to me that you need to do some research on what it means to instantiate an object. Generally objects are instantiated at load time, then simply activated and deactivated as needed during run time. This method is way more performant and helps alleviate the issue of accidentally creating memory leaks (filling up your RAM with tons of object instances).
This is not as important, especially since you are learning and prototyping, but try to extract things into methods where you can. You could put the code for picking up and dropping cats into PickupCat(GameObject cat) and DropCat() methods. This really improves the readability and reusability of your code.
So, refactoring your code based on the sugestions (plus a few extra touches):
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PlayerCatching : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text playerScore;
    private int playerScoreInt;

    public Text catHoldCount;
    public List<GameObject> cats;
    private const int maxHeldCats = 3;

    private void Start()
    {
        playerScoreInt = 0;
        cats = new List<GameObject>();
        playerScore.text = playerScoreInt.ToString();
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        playerScore.text = playerScoreInt.ToString();
        catHoldCount.text = cats.Count.ToString();

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.F))
        {
            DropCat();
        }
    }

    private void OnTriggerStay(Collider other)
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && other.gameObject.CompareTag("Cat"))
        {
            PickupCat(other.gameObject);
        }
    }

    private void PickupCat(GameObject cat)
    {
        if (cats.Count >= maxHeldCats)
            return;

        playerScoreInt++;
        cat.SetActive(false);
        cats.Add(cat);
    }

    private void DropCat()
    {
        if (cats.Count <= 0)
            return;

        GameObject releaseCat = cats[cats.Count - 1];
        Vector3 catReleasePosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, transform.position.y + 1, transform.position.z);
        releaseCat.transform.position = catReleasePosition;
        releaseCat.SetActive(true);
        cats.remove(releaseCat);
    }
}

Note that I changed the input for E to GetKeyDown instead of GetKey. I also added a constant for the maxHeldCats to replace your hardcoded value. You also had unnecessary using directives.
That should not only simplify reading the code, but also the execution, because now your PC doesn't have to create and destroy objects the whole time, it just manipulates what is already there.
As a final note, I would recommend the variable names be changes to something clearer:
Text playerScoreText;
int playerScore;

Text catHoldCountText;
List<GameObject> heldCats;

I hope this helps. Let me know if and how this works for you please!

"Rather, when a cat is picked up, disable the object and add it to the list"
That's actually a really good idea. I completely forgot that the gameobject is already there, so I might as well just add it to the list. I could also activate it then set it's position to the relative position near the player I'd like.
Also for the inconsistent functionality, when I built and ran the game, it works perfectly. I wonder why it was being wonky in the editor. It might honestly be what you said on how instantiating objects are a bit weird so different computers will work better. Thanks for ur advise

This works perfectly. Thank you

Great! I'm glad. I suspect that the GetKey used in OnTriggerStay would cause some issues with dropping the cats since OnTriggerStay runs every frame while the object is in the trigger and GetKey is true as long as the key is down instead of just the frame in which it was pressed. Hence why I changed it to GetKeyDown.
